# Error 500 sin encontrar causa

Tags: php, wordpress, google-search-console

que tal?

Actualmente estoy terminando un proyecto donde todo en un principio se ve que no tiene ningun problema. La página es la siguiente.

> http://www.vistalegrerealty.com/

Sin embargo en el google search console y al inspeccionarlo en Chrome en la pestaña de "Network" me sale un error 500. Sin embargo ya cheque el archivo .htaccess, ya cambie los ajustes de PHP para mejorar los tiempos de ejecucion y los tamaños de subida, actualice todos los archivos de Wordpress y de plugins (cabe destacar que el problema se presentaba desde antes de actualizar los archivos) y aun no se que ocasiona el error (y mas por que desde el lado del tema todo se ve en buen estado) ¿Que mas puede ocasionar este problema?. Les adjunto las fotos tanto de Search Console como del modo inspeccionar de Chrome.
[image: Imagen del inspeccionar de Google]

[image: Imagen De Google Search Console]

[image: Paginas con este error]

Comment: El camino más directo para encontrar el error sería revisar tu log de errores en el servidor (PHP), el error 500 indica un problema en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

1) chequea la versión de php que estás utilizando en el servidor

2) deshabilita los plugins y ve habilitándolos uno por uno para ver si el fallo viene por ahí

3) por ultimo repasa el php de los ficheros que hayas modificado.

Ya nos cuentas si funcionó

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda y comentarios. De momento el error log me coloca un error en un archivo PHP del plugin js_composer. El error dice que es: 
>PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
y en la linea de PHP aparece lo siguiente.

foreach ( self::$sc[ $tag ]['params'] as $index => $param ) {
   if ( $param['param_name'] == $param_name ) {
    return self::$sc[ $tag ]['params'][ $index ];
   }
  }

  return false;

Comment: en ese caso: paso 1) comprobar la versión de php que estas utilizando. Lo has hecho?